# Google cloud Backend service is unhealthy - 502 error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-load-balancer

I believe I have a pretty straight forward set up but I am receiving the dreaded "backend service is unhealthy" notification on my load balancer in google cloud. I will list out steps I have taken so far to provide as much info as possible as I know this could be many things.

- I created a VM in compute engine hosting wordpress
- I created an unmanaged instance group linked to that VM
- I created a load balancer (HTTPS),
- I created a HTTP backend service linking to my instance group
- I created a health check, protocol HTTP, port 80, left everything else as default
- I created a new front end HTTP, port 80, premium, reserved a new static IP address
- I pointed my domain at the new load balancer

It's worth mentioning at this point I tested I could access the web page stored on the VM without any issues.

- I then created a HTTPS front end, protocol HTTPS, port 443, premium
- I set the value of the IP to be the same as the value of the static IP I reserved when creating the HTTP front end.
- I created a new google cloud managed certificate, which was provisioned successfully

At this point I tested again and could no longer access the site and I received the 502 error on the web page.

- I created two firewall rules both set to ingress, allow-health-checks, 130.211.0.0/22
  35.191.0.0/16. the only difference between the two is one is set to tcp 80 and one is set to tcp 443, I was just trying to cover off both in case. I also did try one without the other but that made no difference.

Now I am pretty stuck as I am not seeing any other potential steps I could take to resolve this issue.

I would be grateful for any potential solutions.

Cheers

Comment: What is the error you are seeing under the load balancer menu? You can also check this official [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs) steps for load balancer in GCP. 

Also, is this the [guide](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) you followed? if not, you can use this as reference to your use case.

Comment: Hi @AlexG firstly, thanks for coming back.

Comment: The guide that best suited my use case was this one https://docs.bitnami.com/google-templates/how-to/configure-lb-ssl-google-templates/ and these were the steps I have followed. However when I encountered problems I did review the guide you have provided a link to. as well as a number of other google docs "health checks overview", "trouble shooting HTTP(S)" load balancer" "setting a simple HTTP load balancer" "SSL Certificates overview" & a few more besides.

There is no error aside from a yellow flag indicating that 1 backend service is unhealthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to overcome this issue by following this guide. https://www.jiyuulife.net/google-cloud-cdn-for-gcp-wordpress/ In case anyone has similar issues.

There isn't a lot of good material out there for unmanaged IG's linked to existing VM's. I found even googles documentation to be a little light on the subject. Sometimes you do want to provide load balancing to existing VM's to make use of CDN without the redundancy or expense.

I welcome additional contributions here.